# That's not really an ampersand, is it?

Tags: bug, design, help-center

From our ["what's reputation" help page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation):

[image]

Can we get a good old ampersand please? The ligature has been around for almost 2000 years (early instances can be seen in Pompeian graffiti), I'm kinda used to it.

Comment: see also: [What's this cohhunity bulletin?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3529/whats-this-cohhunity-bulletin) and [clean reads like dean, letter spacing](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/5180/clean-reads-like-dean-letter-spacing)

Comment: It is an ampersand.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa No, it is not.

Comment: @YannisRizos Of course it is.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa Hm... I'm starting to see it now...

Comment: related: [The “&” in the title font doesn't look anything like an ampserand](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3469/the-in-the-title-font-doesnt-look-anything-like-an-ampserand)

Answer (score 4):

That is apparently how [Gregory House writes it.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93372/what-font-is-used-on-the-programmers-stack-exchange-site)  (It's not Lupus!)

An examination of the symbols on the top row of the keyboard yields:

[image]

Where a couple of symbols (namely the @ and the *) are conspicuously missing.  Apparently Hugh Laurie never wrote them on the whiteboard during the entire series.

UL is an abbreviation for a number of medical terms, including Undifferentiated Lymphoma.  It is entirely possible that the maker of the font confused that abbreviation with the ampersand.

Unfortunately, it requires a font editor (and an intern with a black marker and a steady hand) to fix it.

Comment: Hey, perhaps we can get Hugh Laurie to draw a normal ampersand for us. You think he'll do it for some sweet Stack Exchange swag?

Comment: I think he would find that irresistible.  Maybe a [Unicorn with an English accent](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/jon-skeet-unicorn-painting.jpg)?

Comment: Sounds like a plan! And in the highly unlikely case it doesn't work, we could always [replace the damn font](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/5239/25936).

Comment: We could have a community member with good, clear whiteboard handwriting make a new font for us. Maybe hold a contest?

Comment: @WorldEngineer do you really want it *that* clear? That'd be bad whiteboard handwriting if you ask me.